# What is the intuition behind a G-matrix? Any important applications in science and engineering?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In 2012, Miroslav Fiedler and Frank J. Hall (Linear Algebra) introduced a new class of matrices called as "G-matrices". In fact, a real square matrix $A$ is called a $G$-matrix, if $A$ is nonsingular and there exist nonsingular diagonal matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ such that
$$
(A^{-1})^\top = D_1 A D_2
$$

They present a potpourri of results like all orthogonal matrices, diagonal matrices are $G$-matrices. Otherwise, they don't give much insight into how they came up with this new class of matrices. The conclusion in the paper gives a summary of mathematical properties but not any ideas like where these $G$-matrices can be applied.

Is it correct to say that $G$-matrices are some generalization of orthogonal matrices?

[G-matrix (2012) Paper Link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379511005453)

Comment: It is definitely correct to say that $G$ matrices are a generalization of orthogonal matrices. In particular, orthogonal matrices are $G$ matrices for which the equality holds with $D_1=D_2=I$